# Decomposition of reversed processes

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Consider a reversed filtration $(\mathcal{F}_k)_{k \geq 0} $ $(\mathcal{F}_{k+1} \subset\mathcal{F}_k),$ $(X_k)_{k \geq0}$ is a processes in $L^1,\mathcal{F}_k$-adapted.

Is it possible to decompose $X_k=Y_k+W_k,$ where $(Y_k,\mathcal{F}_k)_{k \geq 0}$ is a reversed martingale, $(W_k)_{k} $ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-predictable ? In other word, the decomposition of Doob, does it holf for reversed processes ? How ? What about the Krickerberg decomposition ?

References are welcomed!

Comment: What happens if you emulate the proof of the usual Doob’s decomposition?

Comment: Supposing the decomposition holds, then $E[X_k-W_k|\mathcal{F}_{k+1}]=X_{k+1}-W_{k+1}$ so that $E[X_k-X_{k+1}|\mathcal{F}_{k+1}]=W_k-W_{k+1},$ if we choose $W_0=0,W_k=\sum_{q=0}^{k-1}E[X_{q+1}-X_{q}|\mathcal{F}_{q+1}],k \geq 1$ $W_k$ is not $\mathcal{F}_k$-predictable